# Create columns from a .log/.txt file - python

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a .log file with pandas that looks like this

```
10:30:03:8600 Rx 1 0x014 9 B5 45 5B 81 95 02 50 01  0x6E (Enhanced)         
10:30:04:0280 Rx 1 0x015 8 77 B9 60 AE 8C 47 E6 20  0x3A (Enhanced)   
...   
[93 rows x 1 columns]
```

So aparrently everything is in 1 column

What I want to do is:

Split the 1 column that I have into each column that is separated by each space " " and add a header.

For this I have tried:

> df = pd.read_csv('df.log',
>                    delimiter = ' ',
>                    names = ['Time', 'Tx/Rx','ID' 'Temp','Pressure' ...])

I want to be able to read the values from **B5** to **01** from the 1st row. So, after I split the one column into more columns I plan to use `.iloc` like `df.iloc[5:12]` for all the rows.

I want in to look this, so I can easily read the data:

> 'ID'        'Temp',  'Pressure'     ...
>    B5      45         5B   ...
>    77      B9         60   ...

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help with answering your question, can you add an example of the output that you would like to obtain?

Comment: whats the delimiter and end of line terminator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a single line solution for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv("df.log", delimiter = " ", names = ['Time', 'Tx/Rx','ID','Temp','Pressure' ...])
```

Notice that delimiter is in this case a whitespace.
If you want to get rid of the index when printing it:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Please try it out and tell me if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is apply `str.split` and then convert the column with list to individual columns.

```py
>>> df1 = df.loc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x.split())

>>> df1
0    [10:30:03:8600, Rx, 1, 0x014, 9, B5, 45, 5B, 8...
1    [10:30:04:0280, Rx, 1, 0x015, 8, 77, B9, 60, A...
Name: 0, dtype: object

>>> pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), columns=list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"))
               A   B  C      D  E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M     N           O
0  10:30:03:8600  Rx  1  0x014  9  B5  45  5B  81  95  02  50  01  0x6E  (Enhanced)
1  10:30:04:0280  Rx  1  0x015  8  77  B9  60  AE  8C  47  E6  20  0x3A  (Enhanced)
```